# Why does ReactJS handle radio `checked` attr differently from other attrs?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

**tl;dr** React refuses to honor `checked={checkThisOption}` on inputs, even though it honors `data-ischecked={checkThisOption}` perfectly on the same set of inputs.

I haven't made this work on jsfiddle, but I have reproduced the issue using [this code](https://gist.github.com/tomprogers/54e70947c4b95b60a7aa).

**the long version**

I've got a simple ReactJS component that presents a list of radio buttons to the user. The user is supposed to be able to pick a radio and then push a button to confirm their choice.

Here's the component def (note: I'm using ES6 & webpack):

```
import React from 'react';

class Widget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            currentValue: null // tracks currently-selected choice, by its value
        };
    }

    onClickOptionRadio = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            currentValue: String(event.currentTarget.value)
        });
    }

    onConfirm = (event) => {
        if(!this.props.onChange) return;
        this.props.onChange(this.state.currentValue);
    };

    render() {
        let choices = this.props.choices;
        let currentValue = this.state.currentValue;

        return (
            <div className="Widget">
                <ol className="choices">
                    {
                        choices.map((choice, i) => {
                            // decide whether to mark radio as checked:
                            // - if no current choice, check first radios
                            // - otherwise, check radio matching current choice
                            let noCurrentChoice      = (currentValue === null);
                            let drawingFirstChoice   = (i === 0);
                            let thisChoiceIsSelected = (String(choice.value) === currentValue);
                            let checkThisOption      = thisChoiceIsSelected || (noCurrentChoice && drawingFirstChoice);

                            return (
                                <li key={i}>
                                    <input type="radio" name="choices"
                                        value={choice.value}
                                        onChange={this.onClickOptionRadio}
                                        checked={checkThisOption?'checked':''}
                                        data-ischecked={checkThisOption}
                                        />

                                    <label>{choice.label}</label>
                                    {' '}

                                    {checkThisOption ? 'CHECKED' : ''}
                                </li>
                            );
                        })
                    }
                </ol>

                <button onClick={this.onConfirm}>Confirm choice</button>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Widget;
```

Here's the owning component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Widget from 'components/widget';

class Owner extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        let choices = [
            { value: 10, label: 'First' },
            { value: 20, label: 'Second' },
            { value: 30, label: 'Third' }
        ];

        return (
            <div className="Owner">

                <Widget
                    choices={choices}
                    />

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Owner;
```

Here's a gif of it in action:

[image: Live demo]

Note several things from the video:

- the logic clearly works for checking the first radio on initial render
- the other radios don't become checked when the user clicks on them
- however, the logic clearly works for identifying which item is selected, as indicated by `margin-right: 2rem` on the radio that ought to be checked
- the text indicating which option has been chosen is accurate throughout
- when I click a radio, the `componentWillUpdate` method fires only for the Widget itself; none of its ancestors update

I think this demo proves that this isn't a case of the `Widget` instance being replaced by a different instance whose state is empty. The fact that the current selection is accurately reflected by a `data-` attr *on the input*, as well as plain text, shows that the state is persisting as desired. I am certain this unwanted behavior is by design, and I want to know how to work around the bizarre, exceptional logic that React applies to the form-related properties of controlled inputs.

Why do I think the current behavior is wrong? I don't want the owning component to know about each radio click -- the owner should bind to Widget's `onChange` method to be notified once a final choice is made.

This is a simplified example. The real component is more complicated, but the principle is the same: just as a date-picking component may have lots of internal state that the owning component is unaware of (like what time scale to show, which year, month, or week to display, etc.), so too does this component have some interesting internal state that owning components have no business managing.

As far as I can tell, I've done this exactly correctly. The component publishes its important state updates via `onChange(event, newValue)`, which owning components should bind to. I think it's quite clear that React is *deciding* to not update the `checked` attr on these inputs, even though it's clearly capable of updating other attrs on the same elements in response to the same user actions.

Note that the owner isn't *currently* listening for the `onChange`, but that shouldn't matter: the child component should be able to manage its own internal state even when the owner isn't listening. And I reject the assertion that the radio state can't be accurate simply because Owner isn't providing a `currentValue` via props: Widget is plainly managing and rendering its state without that prop. React must be doing something special to prevent `checked` from being handled according to the rules that apply to *every other element and attribute*. This is an exception, and I think it's a bad one.

Finally, note that this problem only seems to occur when this component is beneath a certain comp-tree depth. When it is the only component in a Flux "page" or a Redux "container," it works great. When it's nested more deeply, it fails as I've described. I haven't yet worked out a concise way of showing that.

Any advice is appreciated. As far as I can tell, here React is violating its own stated rules, and I expect this behavior to frustrate building other stateful components that are built around vanilla `input`s.

**Edit:** I corrected the generated `name`s for the radios, and updated the demo to reflect it. Apologies to anyone who started chasing that stuff down.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/fcLebhcd/ . You may not be passing the correct data to the component. Is choices an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties? Note that `checked` expects a boolean value, not a string.

Comment: Same here, works fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxeZjX - could it be a browser related issue?

Comment: @FelixKling: yes, passing array of choice. I'll update post with snippet of owning comp. Re: bool/string: it fails for me both ways.

Comment: @gpmcadam: Prolly not browser: I'm using evergreen Chrome. I think your component tree isn't deep enough. When I do this as a top-level component (i.e. directly inside a Flux "page" or a Redux "container", it works fine. When I insert this comp deeper in the comp tree, it fails as I describe. I'll look at beefing up my sample code to capture this.

Comment: @Tom Ideally post codepen/jsfiddle which reproduces the issue?

Comment: @gpmcadam: I will set up a working sandbox for repro/inspection later tonight.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing the issue on jsfiddle. I've charted my own comp tree, and tried hollowing everything out, but the problem only goes away when the Widget is moved to the top. Starting to wonder about ~race between comp updates, even tho I think my earlier experiment proves that's not the case. Debugging suggestions are welcome. I can't post my actual source. Still working to refine a narrow repro fiddle.

Comment: @Tom are you familiar with the `defaultChecked` attribute? (defaultValue, defaultChecked) are sometimes needed for inputs. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value

 the docs are kind of confusing about them, so don't read too much into it.. just kinda figure out when you need them

Comment: @CoryDanielson: I am familiar with `defaultChecked`, and in this case that's not the desired functionality. I believe what I'm attempting is strictly analogous to what we'd do to a text field: `<input type="text" value={this.state.currentTextValue} onChange={this.saveTextValueToState} />`

Answer (score 1):

I've edited it to not use [class properties](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties), and are not able to reproduce:

[image]

Code:

```
class Widget extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      currentValue: null // tracks currently-selected choice, by its value
    };
    this.onClickOptionRadio = this.onClickOptionRadio.bind(this)
    this.onConfirm = this.onConfirm.bind(this)
  }

  onClickOptionRadio (event) {
    this.setState({
      currentValue: String(event.currentTarget.value)
    });
  }

  onConfirm (event) {
    if(!this.props.onChange) return;
    this.props.onChange(this.state.currentValue);
  };

  render() {
    let choices = this.props.choices;
    let currentValue = this.state.currentValue;

    return (
      <div className="Widget">
      <ol className="choices">
      {
        choices.map((choice, i) => {
          // decide whether to mark radio as checked:
          // - if no current choice, check first radios
          // - otherwise, check radio matching current choice
          let noCurrentChoice      = (currentValue === null);
          let drawingFirstChoice   = (i === 0);
          let thisChoiceIsSelected = (String(choice.value) === currentValue);
          let checkThisOption      = thisChoiceIsSelected || (noCurrentChoice && drawingFirstChoice);

          return (
            <li key={i}>
            <input type="radio" name="choices"
            value={choice.value}
            onChange={this.onClickOptionRadio}
            checked={checkThisOption?'checked':''}
            data-ischecked={checkThisOption}
            />

            <label>{choice.label}</label>
            {' '}

            {checkThisOption ? 'CHECKED' : ''}
            </li>
          );
        })
      }
      </ol>

      <button onClick={this.onConfirm}>Confirm choice</button>

      </div>
    );
  }

}


class Owner extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    let choices = [
      { value: 10, label: 'First' },
      { value: 20, label: 'Second' },
      { value: 30, label: 'Third' }
    ];

    return (
      <div className="Owner">

      <Widget
      choices={choices}
      />

      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Owner />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

My browser is Chrome 47. [Here is the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/vjv14ezy/)