# Radio button only works on label click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, clicking on the label for my radio button toggles the "checked" attribute and fires the rest of the click event. However, if I click directly on the input itself, the click event fires but the attribute doesn't become checked. Here's my html

```js
$('.sociographic').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()

  var currentLayer = $(this).children('.form-check-label').children('input').attr('id')
  console.log(currentLayer)
  $('.sociographic').children('.form-check-label').children('input').prop('checked', false)
  $(this).children('.form-check-label').children('input').prop('checked', true)
  var currentID = "#" + currentLayer
  $(currentID).prop('checked', true)
  console.log(currentID)
  // ...rest of click event
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-check sociographic">
  <label class="form-check-label" for='crime'>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="crime" id="crime" value="option2">
    Crime
  </label>
</div>
```

Again, everything works and the click event definitely fires. Literally the only thing that's different is that the prop('checked', false) code fails to do anything. When I console.log $(this) I even get the same input. In fact, the label extends over the radio button and I've tried setting the z-index to 10000000 to ensure that I'm click on the label at all times. Even when I guarantee that I'm clicking on the label, it fails to work when I'm clicking on the portion of the label that's over the actual input.

Here's a picture to better illustrate what I mean: [image]

Note a few things: 1) the label extends over the input. 2) I can manually set the radio button to checked when I enter $('#crime').prop('checked', true) into the console. That's the exact code I'm including in the click event that seemingly doesn't do anything. 3) this is an issue for every button.

I have no idea why this seemingly straightforward radio button refuses to be checked programmatically, and I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The selection of the element is stopped due to the `preventDefault()` call. That said, why do you need JS to do this? You already have the `label` elements setup wrapping the inputs, so the hit area has already been expanded for you...?

Comment: I've always had trouble with checkboxes in React. Perhaps this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365705/why-does-reactjs-handle-radio-checked-attr-differently-from-other-attrs

Comment: Hey Rory - you were totally (er, mostly) right about the issue. stopPropagation() was blocking the bubbling, somehow. I should have thought of that. That said, it's still unclear as to how I was even able to select the input over the padding of the label when the z-index was set so high.

Comment: You need to use @RoryMcCrossan in the future for him to get a notification of your comment. This one should alert him to your reply. That said: take the answer you've got and don't worry too much about why things worked *part way.* Staring too deeply into how JavaScript manages to do unexpected things only leads to madness.